# Don't have access to view this directory or page microsoft azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Please see this site - []

I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC application I have

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

In the web.config however I still don't have permission?? I only have the default routing mechanism and a single Controller with a single action i.e. Home/Index.

Please help.

Comment: How did you deploy the website?  Does it run locally?  What version of ASP.NET?  Does the version .net version match the portal website configuration?

Comment: Deployed via bitbucket.org, yes it runs locally, ASP.NET4.5 and yes it does match the portal website configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two projects which were included in the one solution. The other project was being deployed.